# get the zip code along with messsage

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, forms, product-view, zipcode

When we click on "zip code" & enter "check" button,

[image]

Then we are displaying "Available with 14 sellers" , in front of that text, i want to display entered zip code : "110001".

I need :" **Available with 14 sellers 110001 "**

**result.phtml**

```
<p>
<?php echo "Available with 14 sellers";?>
</p>

<p>
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('postcode')) ?>
</p>
```

**form.phtml**

```
<?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('postcode')): ?> 
<li class="item"> 

<label for="search"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('') ?></label> 
<div class="search"> 


<input placeholder="Enter your PIN Code" class="input-text <?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?>
required-entry<?php endif;?> validate-length maximum-length-6 minimum-length-6 validate-digits" type="text" 
id="estimate_postcode" name="estimate[postcode]" 
value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('postcode')) ?>" 
onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}" />

</div> 
</li> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

ex : please visit [link1](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-battle-station-multicolor.html) & enter "110001" in textfield and click on "check" button.

Comment: can you share estimate action code in controller file?

Comment: @Abdul please check here : http://pasted.co/3d673eba

Comment: can you share also block "shipping.estimate.result" file code?

Comment: check here , Result.php file : http://pasted.co/567720f8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this but not sure

in file `result.phtml`

```
<p><?php echo "Available with 14 sellers";?>
<?php  $addressInfo = $this->getRequest()->getPost('estimate',array()); ?>
<?php if(isset($addressInfo['postcode']) && $addressInfo['postcode']):?>
<?php echo ' '.$this->htmlEscape($addressInfo['postcode']); ?>
<?php endif;?>
</p>
```

Comment: i will try this

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ';' in $addressInfo = $this->getRequest()->getPost('estimate',array();

Comment: Sorry it is my issue. Updated ans pls check and let me know.

Comment: its working now, but its displaying in 2 lines, i want in one line.

Comment: updated ans pls check now

Answer (score 2):

that will show the input too

```
    <?php 

echo "Available with 14 sellers ".$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');  ?>
```

Comment: now for all zip codes , i am geting this message : "Available with 14 sellers 8931"

Comment: that are static text what is relation between seller and zipcode

Comment: same zip codes for all sellers in the site. let me know if i understood wrongly.

Comment: i added the condition change as you required..

Comment: nw its displaying blank value when we enter check button

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to achieve here you said you want to show the search keyword with this text. i asked is there any relationship between them..

Comment: sorry, i didt understood, thanks a lot for your support, i got a solution.